# Delete rows over multiple worksheets in Excel if cell value equals "blank"

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete rows over multiple worksheets (only specific ones within the workbook) if a cell value is blank. Note, the rest of the fields in the row do contain data. So far I have the below however unsure how to specify the worksheets. Can anyone help?

```
  Sub sbDelete_rows_if_cell_blank()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
        lRow = 2000
        For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 1).Value = "" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting your code inside this loop will loop through all the worksheets in the Workbook that this code is inside and run your code in each.

```
Sub sbDelete_rows_if_cell_blank()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find last row in column A
        lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
             If ws.name<>"Sheet1" and ws.name <> "Sheet2" then ' change this line to the sheet names you want to leave out. 
             If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(iCntr, 1)) Or Trim(ws.Cells(iCntr, 1).Value) = "" Then
                ws.Rows(iCntr).Delete
            End If
           end if 
        Next iCntr
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**Updated with D_Bester's suggestion for `if` condition**

---

**Update 2: See Comments**

This will do what I think you want to achieve

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim nws, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Add New Sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")
    If nws Is Nothing Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            Set nws = .Add(After:=Sheets(.Count))
            nws.Name = "Combined"
        End With
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not ws.Name = nws.Name Then
            With ws
                Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                rng.Copy Destination:=nws.Cells(nws.Cells(nws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tom - Ok thanks. After removing the blank lines I then want to combine all of the text into another existing worksheet, concatenating the text from each specified sheet copied. I have written a bit of code however only copies one worksheet. I can send the code if you want however may confuse things more than anything!

Comment: @Alex what are you concatenating with what exactly? Could you post an example?

Comment: @Tom - ok example below.
    Column A of each of the sheets below contain:

Sheet 1:  
Name of Traveller  
Legal Status  
Name of Company  
  
Sheet 2:  
Medical Conditions  
Date of Birth  
Name  
  
Sheet 3:  
Annual  
Monthly  
Weekly  
  
The result I am looking for is a sheet containing:  
  
Name of Traveller   
Legal Status  
Name of Company  
Medical Conditions  
Date of Birth  
Name  
Annual  
Monthly  
Weekly

Comment: @Alex how do these three data sources connect? or How does sheet three connect to the other two? I can see 1 and 2 could connect by name?

Comment: @Tom The descriptions I have used could be field names for system, the field names are split across a number of sheets of which I want to combine all field names together in one sheet. Each sheet will have approximately 300 rows and around 20 columns.

Comment: @Alex Do you have a diagram or something? I still don't see any common value to aggregate all three sheets. Or am I misinterpreting what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Tom - Unsure how to add diagrams here. I will give a better example/ description. So column A contains Vehicle Make, Column B Year, Column C Colour. Each vehicle will be entered in separate rows. All three sheets are exactly the same format. So sheet 1 will have 4 rows of data, sheet 2, 2 rows of data, sheet 3, 8 rows of data. I want to be able to run a script that takes the data from the 3 sheets and pastes it into a "combined" sheet - the result would be the combined sheet would now have 14 rows of data. The first 4 rows from sheet 1, the next 2 rows from sheet 2, next 8 from sheet 3.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my first post with what I think you want. Failing that I'd suggest raising a new question as these are separate issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the sheets, then use specialcells to delete the blanks.
Yoi can also set the loop so it doesn't delete the blanks in "Sheet1"(in this example)

```
Sub DeleteBlnkRows()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            sh.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```